# Junitで、一部のテストのみ実行されない

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

eclipse上でJUnit4を使用し単体試験をしています。
1つのテストクラスの中で、プロダクトコードのメソッドをいくつか試験するように書いていますが、なぜかあるメソッドのJunitのみ動かないです。(initializationerrorが出る。)
@Testの付け忘れとかではなく、クラス全体でカバレッジを測った場合もそのメソッドだけ色もつかない状態です。

試しにその試験できないメソッドのテストコードのみ別クラスを作製し、テストしたとこと「ClassNotFoundException」がでました。

クラスパスは通しており、eclipseもクリーンして再起動などしてみましたがやはり通らないです。
同じような事象でハマったことのある方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか。

Comment: 動かないテストメソッドを含んだテストクラスのコードを提示されるといいと思います。コードがないと、何が問題か指摘するのは難しいでしょう。

Comment: ClassNotFoundExceptionのメッセージをご提示いただけますか